# Trouble in Cloud Server of Iotivity

Tags: iotivity

I'm having a hard time running 'aircon_controlee' application.
I got a auth code from github and I'm trying to execute 'aircon_controlee' but it's working.

auth code URL is 'https://github.com/login?return_to=%2Flogin%2Foauth%2Fauthorize%3Fclient_id%3D5cc655ef49c97302664e' and
execution command is './aircon_controlee 127.0.0.1:5683 github 8f7174caa697d7914312' (in same network).
The output errors are as follows.

Auth response received code: 134

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'OC::OCException'

what():  result_guard(): 26: Invalid Param

Aborted (core dumped)

I guess this error is caused from 'Account Server', Because only this process prints error log (please refer to blow).

2019-02-20 21:08:43:214 [D] authCode: 8f7174caa697d7914312

2019-02-20 21:08:43:214 [W] OAuth 3rd party library github does not exist.

OAuthProblemException{error='bad_verification_code', description='The code passed is incorrect or expired.', uri='https://developer.github.com/apps/managing-oauth-apps/troubleshooting-oauth-app-access-token-request-errors/#bad-verification-code', state='null', scope='null', redirectUri='null', responseStatus=0, parameters={}}

Comment: Hello. Can you please provide us the version of the IoTivity you are using? And how did you build the client ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you don't have `Gitlab.jar` present. Copy it please next to your `account server .jar` from here https://github.com/iotivity/iotivity/tree/master/cloud/account